# Ruby programmer wants to help a C novice to refactor his small C app

Tags: c, ruby, refactoring

A friend of mine needs to learn programming C in school, but unfortunately he has troubles with it and his teacher seems to be pretty incapable, for example, they are using Eclipse IDE and the teacher never showed how to do a Refactor => Rename, for example (so all pupils search and replace stuff manually when they need to).

I promised my friend to help him optimize (fortunately running) app which he copy&pasted with trial&error for hours now. But since I'm a Ruby programmer for years now and touched C/C++ only for a few weeks in a programmer's beginner course about 10 years ago myself, the world of non-OO C is totally unknown for me.

So I would really appreciate some good advice on how to refactor the following small app:

http://speedy.sh/Vnfnw/Energie.zip

It basically reads a CSV (energy/heat values?), computes some stuff, and then prepares some data which should later be sent to GNUplot.

For example, I'm unsure about this:

**Is it good practice to send variables into a function as pointers and manipulate them within the function body?** From and OOP, I'm used to be very careful with such things and try to change variables only by sending them to some method and assigning the method's return value to the variable again, e.g. `x = sum(x, y)` (or with `!` methods).

I'm sure there is a lot more to optimize in the code. I'm thankful for some basic hints on how to optimize the code. It doesn't have to be perfect, but it's quite a mess at the moment, and before refactoring it into the "wrong" direction, it would be nice to get some feedback here.

Thank you.

Comment: You will probably have more luck on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: When you say "optimize", what do you mean? It generally means "make this faster" or "make this use less memory", but you seem more worried about style and good practice?

Comment: I mean about style and good practice. I didn't know there's an area about code reviews, I will likely post my question there. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about optimizing working code, which would be better suited on [codereview.se].

Comment: I flagged it for deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is it good practice to send variables into a function as pointers and manipulate them within the function body?"

If you need to change them (pass by reference) there is no other way in C. It is a standard way. Also, there are no methods. Only functions. Although you can model OOP by structs and function pointers, for the small program it is not worth it. 
You just must be much more attentive when programming in C as any wrong pointer can lead the whole application to crash.

Also I advise your friend to write program by himself and not refactor copy-paste code. From my point of view, the success of refactoring lays in understanding the program much more than on knowing where is "Refactor" menu item.

Comment: Thank you. I moved this topic into the "code review" section.